# How to hide Django Admin from the public on Azure Kubernetes Service while keeping access via backdoor

Tags: django, azure, kubernetes, django-admin

I'm running a Django app on Azure Kubernetes Service and, for security purposes, would like to do the following:

- Completely block off the admin portal from the public (e.g. average Joe cannot reach `mysite.com/admin`)
- Allow access through some backdoor (e.g. a private network, jump host, etc.)

One scenario would be to run two completely separate services: 1) the main API part of the app which is just the primary codebase with the admin **disabled**. This is served publicly. and 2) Private site behind some firewall which has admin **enabled**. Each could be on a different cluster with a different FQDN but all connect to the same datastore. This is definitely overkill - there must be a way to keep everything within the cluster.

I'm think there might be a way to configure the Azure networking layer to block/allow traffic from specific IP ranges, and do it on a per-endpoint basis (e.g. `mysite.com/admin` versus `mysite.com/api/1/test`). Alternatively, maybe this is doable on a per-subdomain level (e.g. `api.mysite.com/anything` versus `admin.mysite.com/anything`).

This might also be doable at the Kubernetes ingress layer but I can't figure out how.

What is the easiest way to satisfy the 2 requirements?

Answer (score 2):

You can manage restriction at ingress level :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "192.168.0.XXX, 192.175.2.XXX"
  name: staging-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-name
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.example.io
    secretName: tls-cert
```

You can white list the IP address for allowing specific path to resolve your backdoor issue. For other you can create another ingress rule with removing annotation for public accesss.

For a particular path :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "192.168.0.XXX, 192.175.2.XXX"
  name: staging-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path : /admin
        backend:
          serviceName: service-name
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.example.io
    secretName: tls-cert
```

test.example.io/admin will only be accessible through source-range.